# How to add YAML config option for a custom doctrine plugin that uses Annotations

Tags: symfony, encryption, doctrine-orm, yaml

The plugin: https://github.com/vmelnik-ukraine/DoctrineEncryptBundle

In the example the annotation `@Encrypted` is used.

The problem is that in my current project **yaml** config files are used instead.

I've tried adding `encrypted:` and `encrypted: true`. But both failed.

Please advise =)

Comment: Mh, what's the error or the "unwanted" behaviour?

Comment: There is no error, it simply doesn't encrypt the data (the fields where I added the `encrypted` option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. This bundle [relies on Annotation](https://github.com/vmelnik-ukraine/DoctrineEncryptBundle/blob/master/Subscribers/DoctrineEncryptSubscriber.php#L135) for its config, so you'll have to use instead of YAML.

You don't have to change all your configuration to annotations, just add `@Encrypted`.

Comment: Is there a documentation that i can use to add the yaml support myself?